# SAS: Dynamically copy a certain number of rows

Tags: loops, macros, sas, copy, row

I have a data set that needs to be blown out a certain number of rows according to a dynamic value. Take the dataset below for example:

```
DATA HAVE;
    LENGTH ID $3 COUNT 3;
    INPUT ID $ COUNT;
    DATALINES;
    A   4
    B   3
    C   1
    D   2
    ;
RUN;
```

ID=A needs to be blown out 4 rows, ID=B needs to be blown out 3 rows, etc. The resulting dataset would look as such (minus a bunch of other variables I have):

```
A   1
A   2
A   3
A   4
B   1
B   2
B   3
C   1
D   1
D   2
```

The following code works to an extent, but I'm having trouble dynamically setting the `&COUNT.` macro. I tried to insert a `CALL SYMPUTX("COUNT",COUNT)` statement so that as it loops over each row, the count is placed into the macro and the row is blown at that number of rows.

```
** THIS CODE ONLY WORKS IF YOU SET COUNT= TO SOME VALUE **;
%MACRO LOOPOVER();
DATA WANT; SET HAVE;
    DO UNTIL(LAST.ID);
    BY ID;              
        %DO I=1 %TO &COUNT.;
            COUNT = &I.; OUTPUT;
        %END;
    END;
RUN;
%MEND;

%LOOPOVER;

** THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK BUT I'M NOT SURE WHY?? **;
%MACRO LOOPOVER();
DATA WANT; SET HAVE;
    DO UNTIL(LAST.ID);
    BY ID;
        CALL SYMPUTX("COUNT",COUNT);    /* NEW LINE HERE */
        %DO I=1 %TO &COUNT.;
            COUNT = &I.; OUTPUT;
        %END;
    END;
RUN;
%MEND;

%LOOPOVER;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unnecessary to use macro.

```
 data want(rename=(_count=count));
    set have;
    do i=1 to count;
       _count=i;
       output;
    end;
    drop count;
 run;
```

Comment: You don't actually need a new variable. `do count=1 to count; output; end;` will work fine.

Comment: Wow I way overthought this one. Thank you both!